# LaTeX section page break

Tags: sectioning, margins, page-breaking

I am writing my CV using LaTeX and I have two pages, the first has a different margin than the second which is what I was intending to. However, while adding the various sections I have the problem that if the wording of a section does not fit in the first page with the section title, the wording goes all to the second page while the title remains at the first.

How can I correct that in order to keep the text up to the limit of the page and the rest to move on to the next page applying also the new margins?

Comment: the standard mechanisms for defining section headings go to some lengths to ensure that a page break never happens after a section heading so there is probably something wring with your definition but as you have shown no code it is impossible to say what.

Answer (score 1):

A rather dirty (manual) solution to this would be to add a `\needspace{2cm}` (or whatever space you'd need for everything you want to stick together) before the affected section.

The `\needspace` macro is provided by the `needspace` package (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/needspace).